# Find all stationary points and determine if they are global maxima or minima

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

Let the function $f: \mathbb{R^3}→ \mathbb{R}$ be defined by

$$f(x,y,z)=2x^2y+yz +\cos(z)$$

So, I calculated the partial derivatives of each variable, therefore we have :

$${~\tfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}=4xy=0~,\\~\tfrac{\partial f}{\partial y} = 2x^2+z=0~,\\~\tfrac{\partial f}{\partial z}=y-\sin(z)=0}$$

I have found a point $(x,y,z)=(0,0,0)$, but I don't know if it is a stationary point and I don't know how to proceed from here to find whether it is a global maxima or minima. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: One of the first questions should probably be does it have a global $\min$ or $\max$?

Comment: Does $(0, 0, 0)$ satisfy $y-\cos(x)=0$?

Comment: its actually y-sin(z)=0 because I did a mistake but I don't think so since there is no room for x value anywhere. However, I found that while replacing the equations after I partially differentiated them. Might be wrong though, I'm stuck.

Comment: @copper.hat yeah probably but I don't know any proper way how to prove it.

Comment: Set $x=y= 1$ and let $z$ vary. What range of values can the cost take?

Comment: if we let x=y=1, then it doesn't fulfill 4xy=0 right? And if we let it be that way then, 1-sin(z)=0 therefore sin(z)=1 if z=90, z=450, and so on. Also, 2*(1)^2+z=0 therefore z=-2.

Comment: Stop thinking about stationary points for a minute, and reread copper.hat's comment thinking about the behavior of the function in general. What does that tell you about the function.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I guess it's gonna be a monotone continuous function if we replace in the function x=y=1 and let z vary in the function. So, in fact it doesn't have a global maxima or minima.

Comment: @PaulSinclair But what all of this has to do with the stationary point, since if we replace x=y=0 the whole thing changes and now we have a global min and max.

Comment: A function either has a GLOBAL maximum or minimum, or it does not.  There is no such thing as having a global maximum "here" but not "there". "Global" means *everywhere*.

Comment: yeah I understand that, but what's your point with your previous example?